# nuget not checking versions when getting the same dependancy multiple times

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

My company are now using nuget to package all our shared assemblies. We've also started versioning them based on semver using tags.

I have a situation where nuget is not working as I would expect it to.

I have 3 shared assemblies....

- Enum
- Common
- BusinessLogic

In terms of package references ...

- Common => Enum
- BusinessLogic => Common, Enum

the reason for BusinessLogic depending on both Common and Enum is that I don't want to have to update Common's dependancy (and rebuild, package, publish) when it doesn't need to use a new enum which has been added just for use in BusinessLogic

So, I add an enum and want to use it in BusinessLogic.

These are the versions of everything before I do that ...

- Enum = 1.4.0
- Common = 1.2.1
- BusinessLogic = 2.0.1

I now add the new enum value I want to use in BusinessLogic to the Enum project and build, package, publish ...

- Enum = 1.5.0
- Common = 1.2.1
- BusinessLogic = 2.0.1

Now, I make my change to BusinessLogic, commit, push, package, etc ...

- Enum = 1.5.0
- Common = 1.2.1
- BusinessLogic = 2.1.0

So, now the dependancies look like this ...

- Common => Enum 1.4.0
- BusinessLogic => Enum 1.5.0

Now I run ...

```
nuget pack BusinessLogic.csproj
```

What I expect to happen is nuget will see that Common needs 1.4.0 of Enum, but BusinessLogic needs 1.5.0 and therefore add a dependancy into the package for `Enum >= 1.5.0`, but there is no dependancy in Enum at all, I think it's assuming that Common will fulfill it.

Is this behaviour by design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with you that the current behavior is not correct. nuget tries to optimize the dependencies to keep them at a minimal set, but doesn't account for this case where the versions differ.

Could you please file a bug on http://nuget.codeplex.com/ so it shows up on the radar?

As a workaround for now, you should be able to add the dependency explicitly in the companion .nuspec file used to build the BusinessLogic package.

Comment: I have the same problem even when using .nuspec files. I use NuGet 1.4.20615.182. Is there any other way to solve this issue?